# Laravel - Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in view but not in dd

Tags: php, laravel

I have this weird problem,

I have this code in my blade view

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="c_{{App\Models\Field::where([['material_id',$material->id],['question',$fillable->name]])->first()->id}}">
```

this returns this error

```
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: create.blade.php) (View:create.blade.php)
```

but when I dump it using `dd()` like this

```php
@php
    dd(App\Models\Field::where([['material_id',$material->id],['question',$fillable->name]])->first()->id)
@endphp
```

it shows me no error and dumps the record's `id`

What's wrong here? why is it working in one place and doesn't in the other ?

Comment: Do not do logic in your view. Do it in your controller, and pass the result to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, so this query has ability to produce error, if it couldn't find an object.

i am sure, you are using this input in for loop. so when you dd it will get you the first object and it exist and render correctly. when you remove the dd it will go and do the query many times depending on your rendering and if it caught one wrong object fetching its going to stop all the script

instead you can do the following

```
@php
 $field = App\Models\Field::where([['material_id',$material->id],['question',$fillable->name]])->first();
@endphp

@if($field && $field->id)
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="c_{{ $field->id}}">
@else
// warning field object not found 
@endif
```

or, you can add @ to suppress the error.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="c_{{@ App\Models\Field::where([['material_id',$material->id],['question',$fillable->name]])->first()->id}}">
```

please notice, executing query like this can cause n+1 query problem, which mean its going to execute the query many time and this is not the efficient way for performance